# Can a plural noun be followed by “due to it”?

Tags: pronouns, antecedents, gerund-phrases

Is it correct to say, for example

“You would put your health at risk by smoking cigarettes, due to it containing toxic chemicals.”

Comment: No, but you can say “You put your health at risk by smoking cigarettes, due to it putting a lot of strain on your lungs”.

Comment: *It* refers to the act of smoking.

Comment: I cannot comment right now but as @ Davo and @Janus Bahs Jacquet stated, *it* refers to the physical act of smoking, not the plural noun *cigarettes*. Therefore in general, plural nouns should not be followed by the exact phrase "*due to it*" alone. However, they can be followed by other phrases such as "*due to the presence of*" instead; "*You would put your health at risk by smoking cigarettes, due to the presence of toxic chemicals.*" Edit: I just came across this site to help people and burn time. If you have any issues with this answer, please let me know so I can improve!

Comment: @Davo - *It* refers to "your health".

Answer (score 1):

Neither *smoking* nor *your health* can possibly be thought to be described as *containing toxic chemicals*. A verb can't *contain* a noun, nor can the type of noun that *health* belongs to.

In the example sentence, only *cigarettes* can be described in that way.

Since *cigarettes* is a plural word, the pronoun needs to be *them*.

> You would put your health at risk by smoking **cigarettes**, due to **them** <sup>(cigarettes)</sup> ***containing*** toxic chemicals.

---

1. If the pronoun is to refer to the act of smoking, a description that's applicable to an action would need to be used:

> You would put your health at risk by **smoking** cigarettes, due to **it** <sup>(smoking)</sup> ***involving*** toxic chemicals.

2. If the pronoun is to refer to your health, a description that's applicable to *that* noun would need to be used:

> You would put **your health** at risk by smoking cigarettes, due to **it** <sup>(your health)</sup> ***being adversely affected by*** toxic chemicals.